getting the size of a directory in an FTP server
We are trying to download a large ( as it looks) dataset from an FTP server. To better manage data downloading and storing we need an approximate estimate of the dataset. I know this question has already been asked and answered , but unfortunately du is not installed on that server and I won't have sudo access. Is there any other way that I could get the directory size?

Does the ftp server support the (non-standard) size command?

the server does support 'size'  but the files are organized in multiple folders and sub-folders. does 'size' get the size of folders too?

The question that you are referring to also has an answer using Filezilla. Have you possibly overlooked that?

Thank you the filezilla trick worked! (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041041/10699830)

Answer using a FileZilla trick(https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041041/10699830)
